# list files based on a pattern in a specific directory - one command only

Tags: ruby

I can make it work this way

```
Dir.chdir(basedir)
puts Dir.glob("#{filename}*").inspect
```

Is there any way to do so using only one command? I want to list

- all files that stat with **filename**
- the the directory **basedir**

## Update 1

```
puts "#{csv_dir_name}\\#{testsuite}*"
puts Dir["#{csv_dir_name}\\#{testsuite}*"].inspect
```

retuns

```
C:\Program Files\TestPro\TestPro Automation Framework\Output Files\builds\basics\logs\basics\2011\07\07114100\login*
[]
```

on the other hand, this code works fine

```
Dir.chdir(csv_dir_name)
csv_file_name = Dir.glob("#{testsuite}*")
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this should do what you want:

`puts Dir["#{basedir}/#{filename}*"]`

Or alternatively:

`puts Dir["#{File.join(basedir, filename)}*"]`

Comment: I tried the first one before posting my question. Even the second one doesn't work...

Comment: Hmm, does it fail with an error or just not return the results you expect?  Could you post some of the surrounding code?

Comment: see `Update 1` -  I am on Windows XP

Comment: Hmm, I guess it's something to do with backslashes then, #glob probably has another escaping pass or something similar. What if you try to replace them before the Dir[] call, like this: `p Dir["#{csv_dir_name.gsub(/\\/, '/')}/#{testsuite}*"]`.  Does that work?

Answer (score 2):

previous working directory is restored when the command executed:

```
Dir.chdir(basedir) { puts Dir.glob("#{filename}*").inspect }
```

Comment: the comment `previous working directory is restored when the command executed` is very important! Could you explain why it is restrored when using your syntax?

Comment: Because it is changed before executing the block and changed back after that.